# How can I create a dynamic tag with ajax call?

Tags: php, html, json, dynamic, getjson

I want to create icons according to the number of passengers and I want to give each icon an id.The passenger ids is in php code.How can I give the id of the passenger to the icon id.When par_key is id, par_value should be id of that passenger.

```
function sta_callStation() {
  var distName;
  var count = 0;
  $('#noOfPassengers, #infoOfPassengers, #distType,#distParams').empty();
  $('#sta_numberOfIcons').empty();
  $.getJSON('StationInfoGenerator.php', function (station) {
    $.each(station, function (sta_key, sta_value) {
      if (sta_key == "numberOfPassengers") {
        $('#noOfPassengers').append("<strong>İstasyondaki Yolcu Sayısı: </strong>" + sta_value);
      }
      if (sta_key == "passengers") {
        $('#infoOfPassengers').append("<strong>Passengers Information:</strong>" + '<br/>');
        $.each(station.passengers, function (i, passenger) {
          // $('#sta_numberOfIcons').append('<i class="icon-user"
          id = "sta_numberOfIcons" > < /i>');
            $.each(passenger, function(par_key, par_value) 
            {
                if(par_key=="pas_id")
                {
                   var icon = document.createElement("i");
                   // icon.id = par_value;
          input.setAttribute("id", par_value);
          icon.setAttribute("class", "icon-user");
          document.getElementById("sta_numberOfIcons").appendChild(icon);
        }
        $(function () {
          $("#sta_numberOfIcons").popover({
            title: 'Passenger Information',
            content: (par_key + ': ' + par_value + '  ' + '<br/>')
          });
          $('#infoOfPassengers').append(par_key + ': ' + par_value + '  ' + '<br/>');
        });
        });
      $('#infoOfPassengers').append('<hr />');
      count++;
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can genarete the html with php and add that with jquery `$('#holder').load('me.php');`

Comment: @silentboy can I load all the php info to the popup box.

Comment: Off course. Write a php file which will dump the phpinfo. Then try that jquery rule.